# Как сменить ник на этом сервисе?

Tags: поддержка

Вот правда не понимаю как, объясните пожалуйста.

Comment: "Ваш профиль" -> "Править" -> "Отображаемое имя".

Comment: Что-то не получилось?

Answer (score 1):

Быстрая ссылка: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/edit/current

По шагам:

1. Откройте основной сайт (не Мету)
2. Кликните по своей аватарке в верхней части страницы. Откроется профиль пользователя.
3. Откройте таб «Править». Появится страница с заголовком «Редактировать профиль».
4. На этой странице отредактируйте текстовое поле «Отображаемое имя».
5. Пролистайте страницу вниз и нажмите синюю кнопку, чтобы сохранить результат.